# Compound Interest Quarterly in C

Tags: c

I have a problem in this code: the output result always has the same value as the principal.  Why?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    float principal, rate, total_amount, interest, i, j;
    int time, year, quarterly, x, y;

    printf("Enter Principal : ");
    scanf("%f", &principal);
    printf("Enter Interest Rate : ");
    scanf("%f", &rate);
    printf("Enter Time : ");
    scanf("%d", &time);

    for(x = 1; x <= time; x++)
    {
        i = rate / 400;
        total_amount = principal * pow(1 + (i), x); //total_amount = total_end
        interest = total_amount - principal;

        printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", x, principal, interest, total_amount);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Best not tot use floats for money - people get upset over pennies going missing

Comment: also, aska  question. there's no question (in fact, not even a useful problem statement) here.

Comment: how to fix this problem? i'm sorry.. i'm new in C

Comment: Can we see some sample input and output?

Comment: what do you mean by output result. do you mean total_amount?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I had understood your *single line problem statement* correctly, but IMO, you are not updating the principal for the next iteration.

you should use

```
for(x = 1; x <= time; x++)
    {
        i = rate / 400;
        total_amount = principal * pow(1 + (i), x); //total_amount = total_end
        interest = total_amount - principal;

        printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", x, principal, interest, total_amount);
        principal =  total_amount ; //see here
    }
```

Comment: I don't think so. compound interest comes from the exponent going up.

Comment: @Julius I am not sure about the _logic_ as I mentioned earlier, I tried to follow the problem statement in hand. Maybe OP can enlight us by explaining the problem a little bit.

Comment: I agree. the bug is really not obvious to me. the description sucks. I am procrastinating. lord. gnight

Comment: @syahjpn that might be a problem with your logic itself. Please explain your logic.